# Pentaho Data Integrator Sending Email: Could not convert socket to TLS

Tags: email, ssl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

[image]I hope you can help me with this one. I create a pentaho transformation that sends an email to a specific account. The transaformation was working before but now it suddenly showing an error like the image attached.

Our Network security has checked and smtp connections and port # 587 is already allowed obt incoming and outgoing. I have been trying to search in the internet but could not find any solutions. The ones I found are needed to be coded using java, but I could not find where exactly to put the changes mentioned. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

**For additional info:**
SMTP:smtp.office365.com
Port: 587

- Tried checking the allowede smtp servers and port # in our firewall, and the mentioned ports are allowed for both incoming and outgoing connections so no issues found.
- Tried using other smtp servers and port #, and still the same error.

Comment: Please, Don't put images for logs and code according to SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask